# How and when is Microsoft Word 365 version in stored in file?

Tags: microsoft-word, onedrive, microsoft-word-365

When I edit a Microsoft Word 365 document, which is stored in a folder managed by OneDrive, I can see old versions of the file, by looking in:

```
File > Info > Version history
```

If I email the Word document to another person as an attachment, I believe that these old versions are not included in the `.docx` file.

1) **Is this correct?**

2) **Are there any situations to be wary of?** e.g. if I share the document via OneDrive (which I normally do not do), what happens then?

Comment: "`If I email the Word document to another person as an attachment, I believe that these old versions are not included in the .docx file.  1) Is this correct?`" - did you try? Just email a docx to yourself & see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, version history in Office only works for files stored in OneDrive or SharePoint Online. For more info, see [Save a document to your OneDrive](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-documents-online-8ba1f596-6bc9-4e35-99d4-e27a40037789).

These file versions are based on cloud. It's not in local drive. There is only one version  (current version) included in the .docx file. If you share it via OneDrive, users won't get previous versions of Office files at all.